# Saving is very slow

Tags: mysql, server, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use TYPO3 7.6.X with news extension.

I have a category "Events" that contains many Newsitems.

When I add a newsitem in this category "Events" it take a lot of time.

I did a System environment check with the install tools and all is Ok (green).

Also, nothing special in the Chrome network Tool.

What can it be like cause ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely a significant impact from reference indexing, especially if you use IRRE relations from within your records, or use heavily populated references.

You can use this extension that I created as a way to defer reference indexing from occurring on-the-fly to being processed as a queue (by a cronjob).

https://github.com/NamelessCoder/asynchronous_reference_indexing

For a TYPO3 7.6 compatible version you have to download/require the 1.2.0 version which is the last one to support 7.6:

https://github.com/NamelessCoder/asynchronous_reference_indexing/tree/1.2.0

If you `composer require namelesscoder/asynchronous-reference-indexing` and use composer to install TYPO3 you would get the right version automatically but for manual installs you have to select it yourself.

The "Background" section of the README.md explains a bit more in detail about why reference indexing sometimes becomes a very narrow bottleneck for performance in backend.

Comment: Thank you for this extension, it is compatible with my TYPO3 7.6.26 version ? or It requires TYPO3 versions 8.7.0 - 9.99.99 ?

Comment: When I installed your extension on my TYPO3 website I get this error : Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool' not found

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that 7.6 compatibility was dropped from the most recent version of the linked extension. You would need to use the 1.2.0 version; it is no longer maintained but the feature it changes will absolutely not change anymore in 7.6 so you should be safe using it. Of course, an upgrade to at least 8.7 LTS is recommended.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a bit of info about manual installs on 7.6, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit strange to give you a proper answer but let me try to explain. Probably to reason behind the slow process could be:

- Server response issue
- TYPO3 installation or Extension issue.

To determine the issue, you can follow the checklist below:

- Check server configuration (You can connect with your server administrator)
- Enable the Apache server log (php.ini file).
- Update TYPO3 version to the latest version.
- Update extension to the latest version.
- Enable TYPO3 error & deprecation reporting (Dir: typo3conf/ext/LocalConfiguration.php).

Check the system log and Apache log to ensure what's wrong going on.

Hope this will help you!